# Colocar Resultado Mesmo Que Registro Não Exista

Tags: mysql, laravel

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta onde apareça na tabela a coluna com o total 0 mesmo que não existam registros naquele determinado status.

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT
    STATUS, COALESCE(COUNT(ID), 0) AS TOTAL
FROM 
    TABELA
WHERE
    ID_CHAVE = 1
AND
    STATUS IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY
    STATUS
```

Nesse caso só tem registros com status 1 e 2.
Mas eu gostaria que aparecesse no resultado assim:

```
 STATUS    TOTAL
   1         3
   2         2
   3         0
   4         0
```

Quero que apareça o 0 quando não tiver registros com um determinado status.

Vou fazer essa consulta em Laravel. Mas primeiro preciso saber fazer no SQL, para depois converter no ORM.

Meus registros da tabela no momento:

```
ID      ID_USER     TITULO                      STATUS
1          1        Espetacular                    1    
1          1        Mais ou menos                  1    
1          1        Muito bom. Recomendo!          3
```

Vejam acima os registros existentes. Só tem o Status 1 e 3.
Não tem registros com os outros status, não existem!

Com o UNION eu consigo fazer tranquilo, mas não queria dessa forma.

```
SELECT COALESCE(STATUS, 1) AS STATUS, COUNT(ID) AS TOTAL FROM TABELA WHERE ID = 1 AND STATUS = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT COALESCE(STATUS, 2) AS STATUS, COUNT(ID) AS TOTAL FROM TABELA WHERE ID = 1 AND STATUS = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(STATUS, 3) AS STATUS, COUNT(ID) AS TOTAL FROM TABELA WHERE ID = 1 AND STATUS = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(STATUS, 4) AS STATUS, COUNT(ID) AS TOTAL FROM TABELA WHERE ID = 1 AND STATUS = 4
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636433/mysql-count-to-return-0-if-no-records-found

Comment: Não tem Join na minha query.

Comment: Tem mais de um jeito de fazer, depende do que vai determinar quantos status são. São sempre 4?

Comment: Seus Status sempre são fixos? (1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: Sim, sempre serão 4.

Comment: Dependendo do caso, até UNION de 4 selects resolve. Agora, se estiver usando alguma linguagem server-side, ou algum programa cliente, fica mais fácil guardar num array associativo e mostrar com um loop for. Precisa mesmo fazer isso no SQL?

Comment: É Laravel. Mas se eu tiver a consulta em SQL eu a converto no Eloquent do Laravel.

Comment: @Bacco, então... pensei em fazer assim, mas não queria usar 4 Selects... Não sei se interfere na performance.

Comment: @Zoom
Na ddl, você coloca o default como 0 ao invés de null. A query trará os valores não nulos, ou seja, os registros com valor 0 também serão buscados. Se não trazer, coloque em sua query: and nome_campo != null se não resolver, and nome_campo =0

Comment: Vou tentar, mas o que é DDL ?

Comment: A questão é que eu quero trazer um valor que não existe mesmo...

Comment: @Zoom é o momento da criação da tabela. Ou você talvez nem precise mudar na estrutura do banco. Teste inserir o and nome_campo = null para trazer os nulos

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: André, porque não posta uma resposta ? Não entendi nada do que escreveu.

Comment: O mais fácil é você inserir os Status que você não tem na tabela com um **ID_CHAVE = GUID**  único para isso, e fazer um case no select e no where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi.
Criei uma tabela para guardar os status e fiz um leftJoin.

```
$totalRating = DealerStatusRating::leftJoin('dealer_ratings', function($query) use ($idDealer){
      $query->on('dealer_ratings.id_status', '=', 'dealer_status_ratings.id')
            ->where('id_concessionaria', '=', $idDealer);
})->groupBy('dealer_status_ratings.status')
  ->orderBy('dealer_status_ratings.id')
  ->select('dealer_status_ratings.status', 'slug', DB::raw('count(dealer_ratings.id) as total'))
  ->get();
```